# overfilled oil, can I drive 1.7 miles to get it drained?

Tags: honda, oil, accord, oil-change, smoke

Ok, I have a 2010 Honda Accord 4 door v6 and would typically get the oil changed on schedule with a local Jiffy Lube. Well I got a "15% oil life" light on my dashboard and didn't have enough money for a full change at the time which normally runs me $70.

So my boyfriend said just add some oil in for now until I can get the proper change, which I did. It started with 1 quart of 5w-20 (that's what the manual calls for) then I added two more quarts, totaling 3. But my light still stayed on and today my boyfriend Drove it and the oil life went down to 10%. He went to Walmart and bought 5 quart of the same brand and put the whole thing in there.

The light is still on, but even worse he said a white smoke was coming from the exhaust, the car was stalling on his way home. So I did a little research and figure it's overfilled. He went to a Walmart which is only about 2 miles away from home thank God, but now I want to get it to my Pep Boys, also only 2 miles away, before it's too late. I'm afraid to drive it. Obviously we both know nothing about car maintenance.

Comment: It's possible the high oil pressure damaged the piston rings. Can you drain a little bit of the oil at the garage? You'd need to lift the front, remove the crankcase protector and open the drain bolt. Then, with the correct oil level you should take the car to a mechanic to check for any damage.

Comment: I don't have anything to drain it with without going to the store :(

Comment: Maybe check the tools you need and see if anybody can lend them to you, or the safer option: ask a nearby mechanic to do the service at your home (it will cost more). But as @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2♦ stated in his answer driving a car with too much oil is a really bad idea

Answer (score 4):

In a word: ***NO!***

Please don't run the engine any more until you get some of it drained. You've got at least 8 quarts too much oil in the engine. This will cause damage to your engine if you run it. You need to drain the oil out where it sits to avoid damage.

Please realize, the "oil life indicator" does not indicate how much oil you have in your engine, but rather *how much life is left in your engine oil.* This is vastly different. The only way to get it turned off is to reset the indicator. You cannot do it by just adding more oil. Running oil a few hundred miles past the due date will not cause your engine any harm. Remember, it's just an indicator.